# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: oracle

A background scheduled task for our system has just recently been giving the above error. It has been in use for a number of years. The only difference being that it has been moved to a new server.

I have tried everything I can think of so if anyone has any ideas it would be appreciated.

This is the simple query giving the error.

```
Select count(guid) from transearch_personnel 
where lower(guid)='fkonings001'
      and ((next_termination_date is null )
      and (termination_date is  null )) group by 1
```

Cheers

Comment: What is the reason for trying to group by an aggregated column? Is that even possible? I don't see the reason for the group by clause here at all...

Comment: GROUP BY 1 means to group by the constant numeric value 1. I don't know why it has worked before and doesn't now, but just remove "group by 1" and you'll get the same result, which is the total count satisfying the where clause.

Comment: Might be a dodgy performance improvement. Does the new server have an identical version of Oracle?

Comment: It was previously giving this error. ORA-00937: not a single-group group function. Strange thing it only errors in the app if you run in any query tool it returns the expected result. I am just trying something else, will report back.

Comment: @KimBergHansen right, I was confused by the fact that you can use column numbers in `order by` clauses.

Comment: Is `transearch_personnel` a table or a view? Wondering if the redundant group-by is being pushed up into the view and confusing the parser. If it is a view, is `guid` a fixed value or itself an aggregate? The exact Oracle version on the old and new server might be useful to attempt to recreate.

Comment: It's a table. I have modified it to this "Select count(guid) from transearch_personnel where lower(guid)='fkonings001' and ((next_termination_date is null ) and (termination_date is  null ))" and it now gives ORA-00937: not a single-group group function again. Version is 11.2 I will ask the client what the old version was. Guid is a column in the table. just a char column contains users windows login.

Comment: client on old server was 10.2

Comment: I think its a combination of using count and lower, I have taken out the lower, they are trying it now.

Comment: its still getting the same error, sod it, I'm off for a Friday lunch time pint. Something might come to me. Select count(guid) from transearch_personnel where guid='fkonings001' and ((next_termination_date is null ) and (termination_date is  null ))

Comment: You said it's only a problem from the application, so is that connecting as a different user to your direct testing, and does that use have a view of the real table, or synonyms, or an object called `guid`? Clutching at straws a bit...

Comment: me too. The app connects as same user and does numerous other queries on that table without issue. going to do a database function that the app calls for this and see what happens. Have a good weekend all.